# Visual Studio 2017 tooltip color issue

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, color-scheme, vs-color-theme-editor

I am using the Color Theme Editor extension for Visual Studio 2017, and I'm having trouble changing the color of a particular section in the editor tooltips.

In the example below, I cannot figure out how to customize the bit with the white background - the method signature from the tooltip showing method overloads.

I have figured out how to customize pretty much everything else with the tooltips, except for that highlighted section.  For example, `Environment -> Tooltip` will set the background of the entire tooltip (strangely enough the `Environment -> Tooltip -> Background` setting doesn't seem to do anything...).

Does anyone happen to know how to control the colors for the text highlighted in white in the example?

[image: tooltip example]

Comment: Kevin, were you ever able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @RichardEverett Not really :(.  The workaround I used was starting from the Dark theme and customizing everything from there.  That theme has a tooltip background color that worked for me.

Comment: For me @Calmarius' answer was correct. Just restarting VS did the trick. It was using Sublime Material theme

Answer (score 3):

It looks like that particular color is messed up when you change theme.

Restart Visual Studio and then the color should be OK.

Answer (score 2):

I get the same issue when I change the Tooltip text background with Color Theme Editor extension. And I have submit this issue to Q&A of Color Theme Editor extension for Visual Studio 2017.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.VisualStudio2017ColorThemeEditor#qna

Answer (score 0):

Still a problem in Visual Studio Community 2019 v16.3.6; still the same solution (restarting) works.